# Expanding the Results View will enumerate the Enumerable

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am trying to write a LINQ statement using Entity Framework. I am getting an error stating "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the Enumerable"
My query is as follows :

```
 IQueryable lis = (from que in _repo.Query<Question>()
                   where que.PresentationImageId == 1 join map in
                   _repo.Query<UserChildCourseQuestionMap>() on que.Id equals map.QuestionId into t
                   from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group t by que.Id
                   into g
                   select new
                   {
                      Id = g.Key,
                      QuestionBody = (from q in _repo.Query<Question>() where q.Id == g.Key select q.QuestionBody),
                      value = (from p in _repo.Query<UserChildCourseQuestionMap>()
                      where p.QuestionId == g.Key

                      select new
                      {
                        Name = gg.Key.AnswerOption,
                        Count = gg.Count(),
                       }).Union(from p in _repo.Query<UserChildCourseQuestionMap>()
                         where p.QuestionId == g.Key && p.UserInputText != null
                         group p by p.UserInputText   into gg
                         select new
                         {
                            Name = gg.Key,
                            Count = gg.Count(),
                         }).Where(x => x.Name != null)

                    }
                   );
```

In LINQPad its working fine but in Visual Studio its not. Following is the image result which i am getting in LINQPad :

[image: LinqPad Result Image]

Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Following is the Screen Shot which i am getting when i expand the resultset:
[Expand Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUMdQ.png)

Answer (score 3):

The message " "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the Enumerable"" is not an error, it's a warning saying that if you expand the + sign the query will be run against the DDBB.

Just click in the + and expand the results tree, it should be ok.

Comment: It doesn't show anything on expanding. Doesn't contain any data.

Comment: This probably just means that your query is incorrect. You can trace the call to the DB and see the exact sql being fired when you expand those results. This may give you a clue @TarunOhri

Comment: I have changed my query to much simpler but still getting error at compile time. Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong ? Code is as follows :

Comment: using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext()){from d in context.Questions
                 join bookingm in context.UserChildCourseQuestionMaps
                         on d.Id equals bookingm.QuestionId into bookingmGroup
                    from m in bookingmGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where d.PresentationImageId == 1
                    select new {
                        d.Id,
                        d.QuestionBody,  m.AdminAnswer.AnswerOption,m.UserInputText
                    } into x
                    group x by x.Id into g
                    select g